# Check whenever server comes online using UDP in C programming in client

Tags: c, linux, udp

i have written a normal udp client server programm in  C programming to send data from client to server and recieve an acknowledgment from it for the message been sent..
so my question is that incase if my server is down and my client sends a message to server ..
how can my client sense whether the server is up or down(nt working).
all sugesstions are welcomed .. and didnot find nythin related to sensing a server.. so please help me on this

the code for client is here

```
 #include<netinet/in.h> 
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <sys/socket.h> 
 #include<stdio.h> 
 #include <arpa/inet.h> 
 #include <string.h> 
   #include<fcntl.h> 
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sqlite3.h>



 void enterdb(char *);


int main() 
  { 
int sfd,l; 
char *buf=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char)),buf1[10]="";//=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char)); 
struct sockaddr_in server,client; 
sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0); 
     int sender_len=sizeof(server);
struct msghdr msg;
 struct iovec iov;


  bzero(&server,sizeof(server)); 
  server.sin_family=AF_INET; 
  server.sin_port=htons(1300); 
  server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

   msg.msg_name = &server;
   msg.msg_namelen = sender_len;
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = sizeof(buf1);
msg.msg_iov->iov_base = buf1;
msg.msg_iov->iov_len = 9;
msg.msg_control = 0;
msg.msg_controllen = 0;
 msg.msg_flags = 0;

    printf("Enter the message:"); 
    gets(buf); 
    char *test="quit";
    if(strcmp(test,buf)==0)
        {
        printf("now exiting\n");
        close(sfd);
        exit(0);
        return 0;
        }            
    else 
        {
        int s;
        s=sendto(sfd,buf,strlen(buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));

        printf("control passed on here and message sent is of %d bytes \n",s);  

        printf("control passed on here again and message sent is of %d bytes\n ",s);    
        //sleep(5);
        int length = sizeof(server);


        printf("%s\n",buf1);

        int x = recvmsg(sfd,&msg,MSG_DONTWAIT);
        if(x<0)
        {
        printf("error");
        }
        /*while( ( x =recvfrom(sfd,buf1,100,0,(struct sockaddr*)&server,&length)))
        { 
        if(x<0)
        return 1;   
        break;
        }*/


        else {
        printf("%s\n",buf1);
        char *recv="recieved";
        if(strcmp(recv,buf1) != 0 )
            {
            printf("**** control is in connect ***\n");  
            enterdb(buf);
            }
        else 
            {
            memset(buf,0,strlen(buf)); 
            printf("MESSAGE FOR SERVER : you sent me the message has been- %s\n",buf1);
                } 
        }
    }



close(sfd);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of detecting whether a server is down is by sending it a message and waiting for the answer for a limited time (maybe 30s, maybe 15 min, depending on the application and the network...). In your case, you'd have to setup a time-out in your client, which you would start on sending a message and stop when receiving the acknowledgment. If the time-out is not stopped before it "wakes up", then it triggers an exception or sets a specific variable (these are usual ways of informing the application that the time-out has elapsed without an answer from the server).

Comment: @imsteffan thakyou for the help.. how can i again detect when the server i up after i shut it down for 15 minutes and restart it

Comment: You're welcome :-) To detect that your server is up, your client should keep sending messages ; as soon as the computer is up, you start the UDP server, and it answers the client which then knows that the server is up. Oh by the way, my pseudo is lmsteffan.

Comment: buddy when i try to get a recieve msg .. when the server is down .that process goes in halt and doesnot throw a error for it

Comment: @imsteffan sorry nt able to tag u properly.. i m uploading the client side code where i used both recvfrom and tried recvmsg too. do help me out wiht it people

Comment: recvfrom code is also there.just let me know what modificcations are to be made incase if my server is not wrking the recvfrom should nt hamng and throw an error.

Comment: i am done with the codeing propely. if any one requires it msg here